# Is reputation +100 for having at least 200 on another site retroactive?

Tags: support, reputation

If one has already joined several sites, and then achieves 200 reputation on a site, will this automatically +100 the other sites?  Or is the +100 only for newly joined sites after having 200 reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of.

You need to unassociate your account that recently hit 200, then re-add it, and you should get the 100-point association bonus.

EDIT:  Note that you can only get the 100 bonus once on a given site, even if you associate it with multiple other sites that have over 200.
(Credit to @tvanfosson and @Thomas Owens for adding the clarification in the comments.)

Comment: I thought you get 100 points once, regardless of how many sites. I've been over 200 on SO and Super User for a while, yet when I joined Web Apps and Pro Webmasters, I only got +100. If you are right, shouldn't I have gotten +200?

Comment: @Thomas -- you do only get +100 once, but if you haven't gotten it yet and one account goes over the 200 threshold, you might be able to get it the first time by un-associating, then re-associating.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just the way the answer was worded made me have second thoughts. Thanks for clearing that up.