# Reputation points for joining more than one Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users, site-crossover

I saw that you could get a [reputation bonus +100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57790/157489) for merging accounts across multiple Stack Exchange sites.

I don't have anywhere near that 200+ reputation, so if that would still apply when I get to 200+ reputation please let me know. I am a noob after all. From what I understand I would only get it after joining another site after having 200+ reputation, which seems to kind of demotivate me from joining more sites till I get the 200+ reputation.

I am a new user, I found Stack Exchange so helpful so many times I decided to join. Having a Google OpenID made things a little easier.

I then realized that Stack Exchange is a lot larger than I first thought, with sites for everything I was interested in: Ubuntu, Linux, Super Users, servers, programming and more. I joined a couple within hours. Though it did not affect my reputation.

I would like a once-off reputation bonus like 10 points once off no matter how many sites I join. Just below the up vote limit to keep me from doing for that privilege and keep me involved with the community.

If I am joining the Stack Exchange community, by joining more than one site, I am not a fly by-night, I intend to contribute; hence joining more than once site. I should get a reputation bonus.

I am a new user and would like to get some reputation for joining more than one site.
Before you dump on me for looking for reputation please consider the points I made.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you have 200+ points on one site you can clear the associations and then regenerate them. This will give you the 100 point bonus across all sites.

**NOTE** Since I wrote this answer the situation has changed and the association bonus should be automatically applied once you pass 200 points on any site.

Comment: How do you do that

Comment: Go to your profile accounts tab - http://stackoverflow.com/users/619760/nelaar?tab=accounts and click on the `Clear All Associations` button. Then click the `Associate` (?) button.

Comment: As I discovered last night, simply adding another site will also add the bonuses from existing associations.

Comment: I will then have to go to each site and re-associate it correct. Some help in that process would be nice. Just to complete the answer.

Comment: I would still like to get a response from the community about getting points for linking to multiple stack exchange sites.

Comment: @nelaar - I don't think you have to do each site individually. If you've used the same OpenID across all sites I *think* it happens automatically.

Comment: I mean that small 10 point reputation for people who start out. If I hear the community does not think that this is a good Idea then so be it. I will wait till I get +200

Comment: It does not work from meta.stackoverflow.com so when I get one of my other accounts up to a point that I can do the re-association and it works I will accept the answer.