# Why do I need to have more than 10 rep to paste links

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have multiple Stack Exchange accounts but I can't post more than 2 links because I don't have enough reputation. On Stack Overflow I have 10. It sucks I want to post nice detailed answers which link to many useful resources. Is this [something that can change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79782/157489)?

Comment: You have 75 rep points on Meta, so you obviously know about that site and understand what it is for, and yet you posted this question here?

Comment: @cody-gray Yes, I was trying to get the rep I need to post the answerer I just spent the last hour creating. But could not post it(link limit) It would have been nice if it would be saved it until I had enough reputation to display it. So all the effort did not go to waste.

Comment: Tying to get the best answer possible but blocked by the spam prevention system. I would still like to have more privileged if I join more then one stack exchange and have asked or answered questions on [more then one site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79782/157489).

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) restrictions are there to help prevent spamming of the site.

You need to gain reputation in order to be trusted, by the system, not to do "nasty" things. The theory is that by participating and earning reputation you are investing something of yourself into the site and therefore be less likely to abuse the site later.

Regarding your update. When you have 200+ rep on one site if you reassociate your accounts which will give you a 100 point bonus on all sites thus lifting you out of the "new user" category.

In the mean time just post the link as naked text. Someone will edit your post to bring the image in line (if that's appropriate).

Comment: Yes, posting the link as plain text is exactly what I'd recommend. I frequently edit questions from new users to make hyperlinks hyper, and bring images in-line. Asking a few good questions will also get you enough rep to do this on your own in a hurry.

Comment: @cody-gray cant post urls as naked text, the are picked up as links automatically, I tried that. It still kicked me out to not more then 2 links error